# Unintentional mayim acharonim

Tags: halacha, mayim-acharonim

According to those positions that maintain that one ought minimize the amount of water used for mayim acharonim:

Is it possible to wash for mayim acharonim unintentionally?

For clarity, here are examples of the types of scenarios I am considering:

A) A person uses the bathroom towards the end of his meal and washes his hands afterwards.

B) A person washes off food residue from their hands and mouth towards the end of the meal.

C) A person washes off a vegetable that he wants to eat towards the end of the meal and inadvertently washes his hands in the process.

In these types of situations, would the water that was used for a different function than mayim acharonim nevertheless be considered to be mayim acharonim? If so, how does one avoid using an improperly excessive amount of water?

Comment: I remember seeing a teshuva in Igros Moshe dealing with what to do if you want to use the restroom before bentching, but I have not been able to find it again.

Comment: Assuming (contra many decisors) that minimizing the volume utilized is proper, why couldn't you simply have in mind that whatever minimal volume used is for the purpose of מים אחרונים and the excess is for whatever other purpose?

Comment: @Deuteronomy It could be that any water that is used at the end of a meal is considered mayim acharonim

Comment: R’ Chaim Kanievski in Shailos Rav vol 1 pg 271 says that washing for the bathroom is sufficient for mayim achronim. However in shu”t Silmas Chaim simian 180 he says that Asher yatzar is a hefsek

Comment: @Chatzkel He could mean to make asher yatzar after bentching. Are these reliable seforim? Many books based on his supposed answers are not.

Comment: @N.T. It is quoted in dirshu if that’s worth anything to you as far as reliability

Comment: @Chatzkel I'd rather see the hakdama of the sefer.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I disagree with your edit. The question stands according to everyone. What the nafka mina are will depend on those other things.

Comment: @DoubleAA where there is no concern to minimize then there is no concern that one has "over watered" and thus washing an additional time for mayim aharonim introduces no problem on that front. There are separate questions that one could ask in such scenarios according to those that are not concerned about minimization, such as whether one must wash additionally to be sure to use at least a רביעית, whether one must wash again using a כלי, etc.

Comment: @Deut so you agree with me that there's no need to limit the question of if you fulfill the mitzva unintentionally to those who try to minimize the amount of water used

Comment: No, I disagree. @treenuts15 takes it as assumed that using too much water is a problem for mayim achronim (lest one give an offering to the Sitra Ahara). According to that position, one ought be hesitant and concerned about the accidental introduction of additional water. For the positions that do not maintain that such an issue is present (i.e. of using too much water), the introduction of additional water is a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

This case of someone with dirty hands who does not want to use a large amount of water for mayim acharonim is brought up in Yalkut Yosef, Siman 181, Seif 13

> יזהר שיהיו מים אחרונים מועטים ולצורך ניקיון אצבעותיו בלבד, ולא ירבה בהם, ואם ידיו מזוהמות הרבה מן התבשיל שאכל, וכן פיו ושפמו, שצריך להם הרבה מים ברחיצתם, יש אומרים שטוב שירחצם קודם נטילת ידים מים אחרונים אדעתא לאכול עוד אחר כך, ויהיו אלו כמים אמצעיים ויאכל פת, ואחר כך יטול מים אחרונים במעט מים. ויש אומרים שאין צריך להחמיר בזה כל כך, ורשאי להעביר את ידיו לאחר שנטל מים אחרונים על פיו ושפמו. ולדינא, נכון שירחץ ידיו להעביר הזוהמא שלא לשם מים אחרונים, ושוב יחזור ויטול אצבעות ידיו במים מועטים לשם מים אחרונים. ועל כל פנים צריך לרחוץ י''ד פרקי אצבעותיו. [ילקוט יוסף הל' ברהמ''ז וברכות עמ' רנא. ועל פי המבואר בהליכות עולם ח''ב עמוד מה]

Comment: Is this a proper understanding of the text?
1) Wash hands normally with the intention not to end meal, eat some bread, and then make mayim acharonim using a small amount of water.
2) Wash hands thoroughly after making mayim acharonim normally
3) The practical halacha is lenient and allows for first washing thorougly and then making mayim acharonim